# Spark Streaming does not clean files in /tmp

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a Spark Streaming job (2.3.1 - standalone cluster):

- ~50K RPS
- 10 executors - (2 core, 7.5Gb RAM, 10Gb disk GCP nodes)
- Data rate ~20Mb/sec and job (while running) run ~0.5s on 1s batches.

The problem is that the temporary files that spark writes to `/tmp` are never cleaned out as the JVM on the executor never terminates.  Short of some `clever` batch job to clean the `/tmp` directory I am looking to find the proper way to keep my job from crashing (and restarting) on `no space left of device` errors.

I have the following `SPARK_WORKER_OPTS` set as follows:

```
SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="-Dspark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true -Dspark.worker.cleanup.interval=1200 -Dspark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl=345600"
```

I have experimented with both `CMS` and `G1GC` collectors - neither seemed to have an impacted other than modulating GC time.

I have been through most of the documented settings, and searched about but have not been able to find any additional directions to try.  I have to believe that ppl are running much bigger jobs with a long running, stable stream and that this is a solved problem.

Other config bits:

spark-defaults:

```
spark.serializer                            org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.broadcast.compress                    true
spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown    true
spark.ui.reverseProxy                       true
spark.cleaner.periodicGC.interval               20
...
```

spark-submit: (nothing special)

```
    /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit \
  --master spark://6.7.8.9:6066 \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --supervise \
  /opt/application/switch.jar
```

As it stands the job runs for ~90 minutes before the drives fill up and we crash.  I could spin them up with larger drives, but 90 minutes should allow for the config options I've tried to have a go at cleanup at 20 minute intervals.  Larger drives would likely just prolong the issue.

Comment: Could you try to find log entries like: `Worker cleanup enabled; old application directories will be deleted in`, `Removing directory` and  `App dir cleanup failed` ? Please check also that your configuration is correct.  spark.worker.cleanup.interval and spark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl are given in seconds. You'll run the cleaner every 20 minutes for the data older than 3 days. Please also check if your configuration is correctly applied to the running pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Drives filling up turned out to be a red herring.  A cached DataSet inside the job was not being released from memory after `ds.cache`.  Eventually things spilled to disk and our no remaining drive space condition resulted.  Or, bit by premature optimization.  Removing the explicit call to cache resolved the issue and performance was not impacted.

Comment: how did you use removing explicit cache.. can you please help